# How to parse JSON response which contains nested JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from an API and store the data to DATA CLASS and sending the data to recycler adapter as ArrayList.

The JSON Array has another array of objects inside, and I'm not able to find a way to properly parse that JSON response.

**Here is my data class:**

```
data class OrderDetails (
val orderId: String, // order_id value from json object goes here //
val restaurantName: String, // restaurant_name value from json object goes here //
val totalCost: String, // total_cost value from json object goes here //
val orderDate: String, // order_placed_at value from json object goes here //
val orderFoodDetails: String // food_items value in json response is an array and i'm stuck here //
)
```

**Here is my Kotlin code:**

```
try {
val data = it.getJSONObject("data")
val success = data.getBoolean("success")

if (success) {
val arrayData = data.getJSONArray("data")
for (i in 0 until arrayData.length()) {
val orderJsonObject = arrayData.getJSONObject(i)
val orderObject = OrderDetails(
orderJsonObject.getString("order_id"),
orderJsonObject.getString("restaurant_name"),
orderJsonObject.getString("total_cost"),
orderJsonObject.getString("order_placed_at"),
orderJsonObject.getJSONArray("food_items").toString() // getting array and storing as a string
)
orderList.add(orderObject)

for (orders in orderList) {
val foodData = orders.orderFoodDetails
val jsonFood = JSONArray(foodData)
for (j in 0 until jsonFood.length()) {
val foodJsonObject = jsonFood.getJSONObject(j)
val foodObject = OrderFoodDetails(
foodJsonObject.getString("food_item_id"),
foodJsonObject.getString("name"),
foodJsonObject.getString("cost")
)
ordersFood.add(foodObject)
}
}
}
```

**Here is the Json response:**

```
{
"data": {
"success": true,
"data": [
            {
"order_id": "17790",
"restaurant_name": "Rotten Tomatoes",
"total_cost": "280",
"order_placed_at": "02-11-20 19:00:54",
"food_items": [
                    {
"food_item_id": "156",
"name": "Rotten Bhajiya",
"cost": "100"
                    },
                    {
"food_item_id": "155",
"name": "Rotten Salad",
"cost": "100"
                    },
                    {
"food_item_id": "154",
"name": "Rotten Soup",
"cost": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

**Required Output**
[Prefered Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANzTi.png)

**My output**
[my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBUMi.png)

Answer (score 0):

do you tried to use GSON or Moshy lib ?
This case will be easier solved with one of this :)

If you don't want to use one of them, just try to replace your for cycle to map or for each, to make it more readable. Looks like you make it right, but can you check the result of try catch block please?